# Disable jquery slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am initialing my jquery slider with the following code:

```
$('.slider').slider({
       range: true,
       values: [0, 5],
       min: 0,
       max: 80,
       disabled: true
  });
```

I then checked the value

```
var test = $('.slider').slider("option", "disabled");
//returns true
```

I can still use the slider (change the value). I have multiple sliders on the page with the same class name. Not sure if that would cause an issue. I want to disable them all so they are just showing the value they are assigned.

Comment: Do you see the problem here? http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/WP29E/6/

Comment: Yes , when you have multiple sliders with same classname, when you do $('slider') you will get an array of elements. If you perform an operation on an array, it should ideally disable all of them as shown in Andrew's example, but my experience is that you will see different behaviors with different functions. Better way is to identify the specific element with an id or use array index.